# Javascript Image Creator/Editor Library

Tags: javascript, images, image-editor

Is there a javascript library using canvas (or any other type) that starts with a canvas size and the user is allowed to choose from a predefined list of images (we are getting from server) and places them wherever he wants on the canvas (using metric system ex mm or cm) and saves the image. An example of why we need this is: The user is going to use a set of labels after that a blank canvas with width and height of an a3 paper will be shown. Then the user places these labels wherever he wants saves the image so that he can print them on an a3 with the spacing and placement of his choosing.

Is there a simple library that can do this?

Regards,

Comment: plain/vanilla JavaScript actually could do the job really well. (This is of course just an opinion)

Comment: yes most probably plain javascript does the trick... but as i am not relatively good at javascript i am more looking for a library